# Is there a common etymology for the kanji 巳 and 己 and 已?

Tags: kanji, etymology

The three characters `巳`    and `己` and `已` are visually very similar, but do they have a common etymology or any overlap in terms of semantic content?

[image: visually similar kanji]

Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: As a starting point to answering this question (ignoring any kanji shape analysis, which is paleogaphy), do a simple comparison between their OC reconstructions. If they sound similar but do not appear to overlap in semantic content, then you can be sure that phonetic loans are appearing somewhere here.

Comment: What is the best way to compare Old Chinese reconstructions?

Comment: Wiktionary has free information on this taken from Zhengzhang and Baxter-Sagart, e.g. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%B7%B2#Pronunciation and https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%B7%B3#Pronunciation - FYI: these two are related paleographically.

Answer (score 2):

- 「巳」depicts a type of *snake*. The word that it represents ([Baxter-Sagart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)) [OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Chinese): **/*s-[ɢ]əʔ/**, *sixth [earthly branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthly_Branches)*) is a phonetic loan.

  <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
  [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
  [image]
  [甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)3915
  [合集30757](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=30757&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
  [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
  [image]
  毛公鼎
  [集成2841](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2841&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
  [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
  [image]
  [郭・成](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference)・36</kbd>
  　<kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
  簡
  [image]
  [睡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)・[日甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)49</kbd>
  　<kbd>今
  [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
  [image]</kbd>
- 「已」(**/*ɢ(r)əʔ/**, *already*) was originally the same character as「巳」, and is also a phonetic loan. Much later on, the two meanings (*sixth earthly branch* and *already*) were differentiated by writing the character「已」without a fully enclosed loop at the top.
- 「己」is graphically unrelated to the other two, and the original meaning is unclear. The earliest determined usage is for the word **/*k(r)əʔ/**, *sixth [heavenly stem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavenly_Stems)*. The meaning *self* is a phonetic loan.

  <kbd>商
  甲
  [image]
  [燕](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2
  [合集13399](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=13399&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
  金
  [image]
  作冊大方鼎
  [集成2760](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2760&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period)
  金
  [image]
  鐘伯侵鼎
  [集成2668](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2668&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>戰國・楚
  簡
  [image]
  [包2](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference)・245</kbd>
  　<kbd>秦
  簡
  [image]
  [睡・日乙32](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)</kbd>
  　<kbd>今
  楷
  [image]</kbd>